# Customizing UINavBar with custom color and without hairline

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar

I want to set my navigation bar to the same color as my UITableViewCell(s), while also hiding the pixel line between the navigation bar and the cells.

The code I've used, in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, is this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.465639 green:0.763392 blue:1 alpha:1]];
```

It removes the pixel line and sets the Nav Bar's color.
However, it leaves the status bar as transparent and my table view appears in the status bar when I scroll down.

How can I add the color to the status bar as well?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a solid colour you could always use:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

To stop the content going behind the bar

And use the new barTint property

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: Thanks! The key is that if you call [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:], you need to customize each initialized navigation bar's color and translucency.